# Obtener estructura de simple form en c#

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, formularios

Actualmente estoy en un proyecto en c# donde tengo que migrar una aplicación de rails a c#. En el proyecto en rails creamos los formularios con simple form y con la propiedad nested_attributes para modificar.

Me gustaría saber si existe, en c#, alguna forma para obtener el request.form de c# y que me devuelva una estructura similar al json que genera simple form (de 1 o mas niveles).

Comment: ¿Estás generando un proyecto ASP.NET MVC? Este tipo de tecnología / proyectos en C# utiliza el mismo esquema de aplicación de Rails, que implementa precisamente el patrón arquitectónico conocido como MVC (Model-View-Controller) y permite utilizar conceptos y flujos de trabajo similares.

Comment: estoy usando mvc2 y la versión 3.5 de netframwork. Las vistas las hemos cogido de lo que se renderiza en rails y pegado, el problema es que una estructura(elementoraiz[subelemento_attributes][0]....) me lo da en una cadena remplazando los [] por %5d y %5b.

Ademas de no obtener una estructura similar, sino, un conjunto de campo=valor& dentro de unos {}

Comment: Hola Rafael, por favor, revisa las secciones [ask] y [mcve]. También es una buena idea hacer el [tour]. Bienvenido a SOes.